# C# windows forms crash in Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, crash

I did a program in C # and use a SQLite database, the program works well in Windows XP and Vista but crashes in the Windows 7! Does anyone know what could be the problem?

tks

Comment: It could literally be anything. Please include error messages, stack traces, exceptions, any details you can. Your question is way too vague as it stands.

Comment: I'm sure running the program through a debugger would uncover the problem.

Comment: Please elaborate on this question. Any error specific question should at least have error messages, if nothing else.
Also, which version of C# was being used.
Kindly provide version and exception information.

Comment: Please reopen this question and then mark it as a **duplicate of [C# Windows Forms + Windows 7 + System.Data.SQLite v.1.0.66.0 = crash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389104/)**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to the memory management confabulator, which was significantly revamped in Windows 7. Access to the garbage-collected heap structure is no longer protected by the virtual runtime environment system. You could try snarfing the file system in order to remove redundant entries.

Comment: Sorry, but that is no specific error

Answer (score 1):

That's a very poorly documented question.  The 80% odds: you are using a SQL-Lite version that contains native 32-bit code.  The regular version.  Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform Target = x86.

Comment: I've done it but doesn't work anyway :x

Comment: Yeah, be sure to not give us *any* information.

Comment: I think that I need an SQLite.dll for Win7, cause when i build the project in x86 the .dll that i've desapear! 

Don't know where i can found that dll :\